# TypeError: Enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'character

Tags: python

im trying to code a plataform for tabletop RPG in python

im starting to coding in python, so i am quite inexperienced nd got some problems

when i try to run this code :

```
def Enter(event,character):
        self.character = self.values['character']
        character = self.character
        Screen = ScreenDice()
```

it returns to me:

```
TypeError: Enter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'character
```

i dont know what im doing wrong, so i'll be very grateful if somebody could help me

Comment: You've defined a function requiring two arguments. Did you call it with two arguments? Also, is it supposed to be a method of a class? Could you post a [mre]?

Comment: Can you please provide the full code, especially where this is being called.

Comment: probably you don't need `character` as parameter as it's overwritten

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are calling Enter. Most likely you did not provide the second argument when you called Enter().

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for `Enter` are `event` and `character`. Whenever you call it you must call it like this:

```py
Enter(arg1, arg2)
```

with `arg1` and `arg2` being replaced with different values. When you are calling it, you are calling it like this:

```py
Enter(argument)
```

with no second variable. You must add that second argument to fix this.